# Remove the path part to access my website

Tags: php, apache, path, dns, lampp

I got a rather easy problem. How do I remove the path to my website called domain.com?

I've got a lampp server where I put one folder called "domain" in the htdocs folder and to access my website I need to write domain.com/domain instead of just domain.com. And when I write domain.com I come to the usual xampp website

Comment: And why exactly do you create a "domain" subfolder within htdocs instead of placing your files in the htdocs folder?

Comment: because in a lampp server you have lamp page in htdocs also

Comment: Err, yeah, so? The index.php in the root folder is just a basic redirect to the xampp folder, so instead of dropping everything in another subfolder you'd be better off putting them in htdocs. There's no rewrite rule needed, and you can still access the xampp pages by going to domain.com/xampp. Isn't that what you want to achieve?

Comment: ok then, There is no real answer to this question yet. So I soppose I need to implement your method

Answer (score 3):

There are a few options, but the easiest is probably using some [URL rewriting](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) given your current setup.

### mod_rewrite in .htaccess

In your htdocs folder create a .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
# If the URL does not already exist as a file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# or directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /domain/$1 [QSA,L,NC]
```

### Virtual hosting with Apache

You could also edit your [VirtualHost container](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/) in the Apache configuration to change the directory as well. If you are running XAMPP then I have previously written about using virtual hosts with [it on my blog](http://blog.simonholywell.com/post/374213855/xampp-virtualhosts).

For example:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin name@domain.com
    DocumentRoot c:\xampp\simonholywell.com\pub
    ServerName simonholywell.localhost
    <Directory c:\xampp\simonholywell.com\pub>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

### A development server for teams (or individuals)

I have also written a large article on [setting up a development or staging server for a team](http://blog.simonholywell.com/post/1516566788/team-development-server) as well, which would be good reading if you are setting up such a system. It allows you to simply add a folder on the server and it is immediately available as a subdomain without any further configuration. This is something called mass virtual hosting.

Comment: I've tried the mod_rewrite method and I haven't succeded yet. I have done something wrong. DO I need to restart my lampp server?

Comment: Is mod_rewrite enabled on your server? The rewrite rules I pasted above are untested, but look right.

Comment: yes it is. I used phpinfo() to confirm it. And it was shown up in the loaded modules after searching the string `mod_rewrite`. If I use your example above and enter domain.com it is like nothing happened. I go to the /xampp folder?

Comment: I still need to enter domain.com/domain

Comment: I don't know what is wrong there. I have updated the code slightly, but it should still work. If it still does not work you could try removing the two lines beginning `RewriteCond` and see if that makes a difference for you.

Comment: Or there any default configs in httpd.conf file?

Comment: I am sorry but I do not know what is wrong. Take a look at the mod_rewrite manual and particularly the logging section. This allows you to log all the activity the module is processing. Perhaps that will give a clue as to why this is not workign.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a virtual host, check the apache [name based virtual host documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/vhosts/name-based.html). If you're running on windows you could follow this [guide](http://apptools.com/phptools/virtualhost.php), if you're on linux/unix you could try the following [guide](http://www.debuntu.org/2006/02/22/7-virtual-hosting-using-apache-2)